# I'm only getting hostname as output but the main requirement is for the backup of the running configuration of Cisco IOS device

Tags: python-3.x

Importing Packages

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
from netmiko import Netmiko
import getpass
import logging
import sys
import time
```

Main Output file

```
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = open("Script_output_Devicebackup_Rint.txt", "a")

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.log.write(message)

    def flush(self):
        pass


sys.stdout = Logger()


def to_doc_a(file_name, varable):
    f = open(file_name, 'a')
    f.write(varable)
    f.write('\n')
    f.close()


def to_doc_w(file_name, varable):
    f = open(file_name, 'w')
    f.write(varable)
    f.close()


file_names = "failed_Device.txt"
# Clearing all the old info out of the results.csv file
to_doc_a(file_names, "")

##getting system date
day = time.strftime('%d')
month = time.strftime('%m')
year = time.strftime('%Y')
today = day + "-" + month + "-" + year

print(
    "Script to take back up of device \nScript output will be saved in Script_output_Devicebackup.txt file\nPlease enter Username:")
username = input(" ")
password = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
```

Telnet connectivity to the device

```
device_telnet = {
    "host": " ",
    "username": username,
    "password": password,
    "device_type": "cisco_ios_telnet",

}
device = {
    "host": " ",
    "username": username,
    "password": password,
    "device_type": "cisco_ios",

}
##opening IP file
ipfile = open("device_file.txt")

for line in ipfile:
    try:
        device['host'] = line.strip("\n")
        device_telnet['host'] = line.strip("\n")
        ipname = line.strip("\n")
        print('~' * 79)
        print("Connecting Device ", line)
        try:
            # print('Trying SSH')
            net_connect = Netmiko(**device)
            if net_connect.check_enable_mode():
                print('SSH connection successful ')
        except:
            print('SSH failed')
            try:
                # print('Trying Telnet')
                net_connect = Netmiko(**device_telnet)
                if net_connect.check_enable_mode():
                    print('Telnet connection successful')
            except:
                print('Telnet failed')
                print('unable to connect to device using shh and telnet')
                to_doc_a(file_names, line)
                continue
        net_connect.enable()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Getting the hostname but I'm not getting the running configuration of device

```
        hostname = net_connect.send_command('show run | i hostname')
        #name = hostname.split(",")
        devicename = (hostname.split()[1])
        print("Working on " + devicename)
        print("Reading the running config of " + devicename)
        output1 = net_connect.send_command('show version')
        time.sleep(3)
        print(output1)
        filename = devicename + '(' + device['host'] + ')' + '_' + today + ".txt"
        saveconfig = open(filename, 'w+')
        saveconfig.write(output1)
        saveconfig.close()
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Configuration saved to file", filename)

        net_connect.disconnect()
    except:
        continue
ipfile.close()
print("\nAll device completed")
```